# how to get minimum dates in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

How can i get a minimum date of some columns with dates field.I know i can use the min function(formula) with numbers but not with dates.
is this possible using calculated columns if not would i be able to do this using a workflow?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `MIN()` function for the dates in the calculated column to get the min date in a set of dates.

Here are my testing results:

Date and Time:

[image]

[image]

Date Only:

[image]

**Update:** Use `ISBLANK()` function.

Use the following formula:

If the one of the date fields (date1,date2,date3 ...) is empty, display empty instead of "30/12/1899".

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(date1),ISBLANK(date2),ISBLANK(date3)),"",MIN(date1,date2,date3))
```

[image]

Or use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(date1),ISBLANK(date2),ISBLANK(date3)),"",MIN(date1,date2,date3))
```

If all date fields are empty, show blank.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joanna W. I Actually taught MIN function won't work for date.Will there be a way how i can check for empty fields before applying the MIN function.Because now it shows 30/12/1899 if the date values are empty

Comment: check my update in the answer.

Comment: Actually just tried that out using ISBLANK :)  Thanks a lot

Comment: I have one more question though..i have a scenario where the first column is the only one with a date. In this case its showing blank how can I show the values instead of blank. Thanks

Comment: Check the last formula in my answer. =IF(AND(ISBLANK(date1),ISBLANK(date2),ISBLANK(date3)),"",MIN(date1,date2,date3))